# Getting gps location updates from native/jni in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-gps

I know that GPS location using Java can be obtained on change in the following way. I know that this excludes checking and asking for permissions, but for this example this is irrelevant.
Full implementation in `MainActivity.java` you can find here [link](https://gist.github.com/austrisu/2d1da5347505609c307de6bb912551e0)

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Listener itself

```java
    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

The thing I want to achieve is to get the same location data from JNI native code. I know that from C++ I could find all java functions/classes, initialize, and use them. The only thing I don't know how, and there are limited examples on the internet.

What I know is that for example, I initialize a new object in the following way.

```cpp
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject a=(*env)->NewObject(env,cls, methodID, 5);
```

I would like to have some pointers on how to proceed with this and implement this GPS location tracking in JNI.

Comment: How about keeping the listener etc in Java and have a specific method in native code that the Java listener can call when the location has changed?

Comment: Then it would lose the point of having native code. My goal is to implement this functionality from native code.

Comment: Then help me to understand your situation: Usually, you only move time-critical/performance-critical stuff into native code. What are you trying to do with the GPS location that is so performance/time-critical that it needs to be done in native code?

Comment: You need to define a class that implements `LocationListener`, which you can only do by writing Java code *or* instantiating a java.lang.Proxy for that interface that routes all methods to a class that implements `InvocationHandler`. Either way, you need _some_ Java code.

Comment: So, tell us, what is "the point of having native code" here, beyond masochism?